# cocos2dx called unimplemented OpenGL ES API error on device with es 3.0

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, opengl-es-3.0

I'm testing my cocos2dx app on Android and I'm getting a error which i cannot resolve. 
The error is:

```
called unimplemented OpenGL ES API.
```

I am testing on Samsung S4, running Android 4.3 which has Open GL ES 3.0 enabled. It runs well on other devices that support open gl es 2.0. Anyone had any similar problems?

My AndroidManifest has this two values set:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I had CC_TEXTURE_ATLAS_USE_VAO enabled  and it looks like the S4 doesn't support VAO (event though i get true in gl.supports_vertex_array_object). I guess it isn't fully implemented.